# Exception in TextWatcher Kotlin - java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "interface kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0"

Tags: android, string, kotlin, android-textwatcher

I have implemented a TextWatcher for my EditText

```
txt_height!!.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
                isExecuteSeekbar = false
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {

                var height = txt_height!!.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
                if (height.equals(".", ignoreCase = true))
                    txt_height!!.setText("2.0")

                height = txt_height!!.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
                if (!sh!!.check_blank_data(height) && isExecute) {
                    val h = height.toFloat()
                    if (rdo_feet!!.isChecked) {
                        for (k in height_feet_lst.indices) {
                            if (height.equals(height_feet_lst[k], ignoreCase = true)) {
                                pickerFeet!!.selectedItem = k
                                break
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (k in height_cm_lst.indices) {
                            if (h == height_cm_lst[k].toFloat()) {
                                pickerCM!!.selectedItem = k
                                break
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    saveData()
                }

                isExecuteSeekbar = true
            }
        })
```

This line generates the error

```
val h = height.toFloat()
```

Debugging the code I noticed that the height variable is equivalent to "interface kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0", the default for the edit text is "175" but this `txt_height!!.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }` return me "interface kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0"

Maybe I did something wrong?

**EDIT**

Using of txt_height

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initHeight()

        body()
    }

fun initHeight() {
        heightList.clear()
        for (k in 60..240) {
            heightList.add("" + k)
        }
        val st = arrayOfNulls<CharSequence>(heightList.size)
        for (k in heightList.indices) {
            st[k] = "" + heightList[k]
        }
        picker!!.values = st
        picker!!.sideItems = 1
        picker!!.setOnItemSelectedListener { index ->
            txt_height!!.setText(st[index])
            
        }
    }

fun body(){
if (!sh!!.check_blank_data(SharedPreferencesManager.height)) {
            if (rdo_cm!!.isChecked) {
                txt_height!!.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(DigitsInputFilter(3, 0, 240.0))
                txt_height!!.setText(SharedPreferencesManager.height.toString())
            } else {
                txt_height!!.filters =
                    arrayOf<InputFilter>(InputFilterRange(0.00, height_feet_elements))
                txt_height!!.setText(SharedPreferencesManager.height.toString())
            }
        } else {
            if (rdo_cm!!.isChecked) {
                txt_height!!.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(DigitsInputFilter(3, 0, 240.0))
                txt_height!!.setText("150")
            } else {
                txt_height!!.filters =
                    arrayOf<InputFilter>(InputFilterRange(0.00, height_feet_elements))
                txt_height!!.setText("5.0")
            }
        }
}

object SharedPreferencesManager {
    private val ctx: Context
        get() = Application.instance

    private fun createSharedPreferences(): SharedPreferences {
        return ctx.getSharedPreferences(AppUtils.USERS_SHARED_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    private val sharedPreferences by lazy { createSharedPreferences() }

    var height: String
    get() = sharedPreferences.getString(AppUtils.HEIGHT,"")!!
    set(value) = sharedPreferences.edit().putString(AppUtils.HEIGHT, value).apply()


}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you set `txt_height`?

Comment: I've updated to add the use of txt_height

Comment: What is `SharedPreferencesManager`? And in particular, what is `SharedPreferencesManager.height`?

Comment: I've updated to add the use of SharedPreferencesManager

Comment: You've got `txt_height!!.setText(SharedPreferencesManager.height.toString())` but `height` doesn't exist in `SharedPreferencesManager`, so this shouldn't be able to be compiled.

Comment: Copy the wrong line...var height: String
        get() = sharedPreferences.getString(AppUtils.HEIGHT,"")!!
        set(value) = sharedPreferences.edit().putString(AppUtils.HEIGHT, value).apply()

Comment: I think you just have to debug your application, single-stepping until you find where the txt_height variable is set to "kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0".

Comment: Every time the afterTextChanged method is triggered in txt_height I have that value, the valorization is triggered by the change in the picker, in txt_height I have the correct value, but as soon as afterTextChanged is triggered, the value is not the desired one

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to first parse in integer then in float.

```
val heightInt: Int = Integer.parseInt(height)
val h = heightInt.toFloat()
```

Comment: Now val heightInt: Int = Integer.parseInt(height) rise the exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "interface kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0"

Comment: Once log the height value

Comment: after initialize with defualt -> 235, after var height = txt_height!!.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' } -> interface kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0

Comment: This is the result of log....when I initilalize txt_height.text has value "235" but when afterTextChanged started txt_height.text has value " interface kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0"